# High CPU usage in RHEL machine

Tags: postgresql, memory-usage, cpu-usage, sar

I have RHEL machine that runs postgres-9.1 database.

In a particular time, `sar` output shows as follows:

Refer link for snapshot: http://imgur.com/gKcOhOX,vNwTpwC#0

where as `%user` is high between 12:50 AM and 1:50 AM & others are asusual, and later the usage of `%user` goes down. I'm observing this daily.

`ps aux outl` shows as follows:
Refer link for snapshot:
http://imgur.com/gKcOhOX,vNwTpwC#1

I had gone through cron jobs and found that nothing is running.

Please help me out what could be the problem!

Comment: Do you have any scheduled jobs within postgresql? Any backup processes or anything that could be triggered to run at a specific time?

Comment: I'd try and get more detail about the SELECT that it says is running.  It could be badly formed and just running out of control.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that some client using IP adress 10.5.183.37 is running some `select` query. This client connected at 00:46 and it's corresponding Postgres process has used over 57 minutes of processor time.

Search for a cron job on a computer with IP adress 10.5.183.37 starting every day at about 00:46.